# What is the best way to delete data by jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I'm trying to delete data from my database using an AJAX request sent by jQuery and I really managed to do it! It works very well. Data can be removed from my table and my database without refreshing the page.

The problem is that I'm 100% sure that it's not the right and the standard way. 
Does anyone have a better ideas for my code?

```js
function alertCmd(asked_id) {
  var user_id = {
    u_id: asked_id
  }

  if (confirm("are you sure you wanna remove " + user_id + " ? ")) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/removeData.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: user_id,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $("#display").load("php/getData.php", function(data) {
            $("#display").html(data);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to post this.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Do you have a specific issue with it? If you want to improve this I'd look in to security. Can anyone delete anything, or do you need a permissions system? How are you verifying the request came from your own site and not an external source? Those are the next steps I'd recommend researching.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to comply with the HTTP standard you should use a Delete request when you are deleting data from the database.

`$.ajax({
    url: 'php/removeData.php',
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: user_id,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $("#display").load("php/getData.php", function(data) {
            $("#display").html(data);
        });
      }
    });`

You should read a bit about [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) and [HTTP Request Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Comment: perfect answer!